# Fully Working iPhone Project Fails When Transioned To iPad

Tags: ipad, ios4, xcode4

I have a working app that I have ran on the iPhone countless times. Everything has worked and the app will run on the iPad in compatibility mode. The problem came when I duplicated my iPhone target and hit "Transion to iPad" When building to my iPad device I get 1 error - Apple Mach-O Linker Error.Does anyone have any advice on a fix for this?
[image: Screen shot 2011-03-24 at 9.48.29 PM.png]

Thanks

Tanner

Comment: Looks like it's missing files. Have you moved the proect at all?

Comment: No, nothing was moved. This is the only thing I found on it but my settings matched this guy and I still get the error http://www.executionunit.com/2011/03/25/xcode-4-duplicating-a-target-to-make-an-ipad-build-link-error/

Comment: Try cleaning your build and checking *all* build settings for escaped paths.

Comment: Everything has been cleaned. Ive even erased the project and duplicated v1 and repeated the same transition to ipad and got the same error. If a correct answer is found I will declare it as such.

Comment: @Tanner: Your long list of questions with multiple answers each suggests you don't bother marking at least half of them answered. I see some pretty solid answers that, as far as I can tell, are correct, but that you did not accept. People *will* start ignoring you if you don't act like a good SO citizen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you read the output you posted? The linker can't find the OAuth library you're using. Verify Xcode knows where the library is.

Comment: But how would it know where it is in the original target but not in the second when the second is an exact duplicate?

Comment: After checking both the working target and the non working have the same search paths

Comment: Ill mark this as the answer as it has got me on the right path.

Thank you

Comment: What was the right path? What did the problem end up being? It's not necessary to mark an incorrect answer as correct; you can answer your own questions and mark the answer accepted (you don't earn anything but it cleans up the question).

Comment: Still working on it and getting the same error. Both are pointing to the same path but only the original target has no errors. Sorry im still a bit unused to SO.

Comment: If you look closely, the yellow-highlighted portions tell you "directory not found for option '-L..." These have to do with the quotes around paths with spaces in them. Somewhere in that mess of paths, something is not properly quoted, since it thinks "/Volumes/Macintosh" and "HD/Client" (and so on, everywhere there's a space) are separate paths. It can't find the OAuth library because something is wrong with how it's quoted. Are you sure both search paths are EXACTLY the same?

Comment: Exactly. I only duplicated the target. Didnt touch any of the paths. Would a screen shot help? I could do 1 of each targets paths.

Comment: Some path somewhere is *not* the same, specifically, it's not wrapped in quotes as it should be. I doubt a screenshot would be effective, since there are a lot of build settings ...

Comment: What it did was header search paths on the duplicate it was putting "/" like /"$(SRCROOT)" I changed these but still get all of the same errors. Ill keep looking. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: You're putting the slash outside your quote. That's a problem. Since "/" resolves to "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/", it's being expanded with spaces outside the quotes. It should be "${SOURCE_ROOT}" or "${SOURCE_ROOT}/SomeSubpath" or "${SOURCE_ROOT}/../Some Sibling Of Source Root/"